# Struts OGNL Long Overflow

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, integer-overflow, ognl

I am adding two list of Long to Value Stack

```
    List<Long> listOne = new ArrayList<Long>();
    List<Long> listTwo = new ArrayList<Long>();

    listOne.add(4031841000000418017L);
    listOne.add(4031841000000337478L);
    listOne.add(4031841000000342064L);
    listOne.add(4031841000000337292L);

    listTwo.add(4031841000000337292L);
    
    addToValueStack("LIST1",listOne);
    addToValueStack("LIST2",listTwo);
```

And I am trying to check if an element in listOne is present in listTwo in JSP using Struts2 OGNL.

```
    <s:set var="listt2" value="%{LIST2}" />

    <s:iterator var="list1" value="%{LIST1}">
    <s:property value="list1"/>
    <s:property value="#list1 in #listt2"/>
    </s:iterator>
```

The Output of the above JSP is

```
    4031841000000418017
    false
    
    4031841000000337478
    true
    
    4031841000000342064
    false
    
    4031841000000337292
    true
```

As you can see, the second element in listOne is not present in listTwo.
But it returns true. Some kind of overflow is happening here. Can someone explain?

Comment: Diagnosing as an "overflow" doesn't make any sense, but that's a separate issue. I'd first sanity-check by making sure `LIST2` is what you think it is. I don't recall much of OGNL very well at this point, but there's nothing obviously wrong. What version of S2 is this?

Comment: Struts Version is 2.5.22 .  Yeah I did the sanity check of LIST2. It is a list containing this single Long Object [4031841000000337292L] @DaveNewton

Comment: You could check the types of #list1 and the first (only) element in #listt2 just to make sure there's no weird conversion happening here. IMO there shouldn't be, but obviously something has gone wrong. That said: oftentimes it makes more sense to treat the view layer as being pretty simplistic and do more prep work on the server side.